# Import Component from different folder Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to ask if how can I import component from another directory?

In my case:
I want to load my component from "components/user/UserInformation.vue" to "pages/User/UserProfile.vue"

Please see the image below:

[image: l]

Thank you so much!

Comment: What problem you have? change `components` to `pages` in your import path

Comment: it didn't find my component path in my page vue.

Comment: your import should be like this: `import UserProfile from '@/resources/js/pages/user/UserProfile.vue'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your project structure carefully. You need to go 2 directories up the structure and then go inside `components/user/`.

```html
<template>
  <user-information></user-information>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import UserInformation from '../../components/user/UserInformation.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    UserInformation
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error using this code.

Comment: @JericCruz I updated the answer, try now

Comment: Thanks for the update but looks like it is still not pointing to my component. I am getting an error "Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <userInfo> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

Comment: @JericCruz that error means that the component was imported 
 but you are not using it correctly. I updated the answer again. Does it work now?